# Resizing images to a smaller size

Tags: html, css, resize, image-resizing

I allow users to add an image and render the image so users can see what they have uploaded. I have a porfolio_photo and a location_photo.  However I can't seem to get the photos to resize smaller when they are uploaded. How would I go about doing that? I followed the suggestion of a stackoverflow user to put width:200px for the portfolio_photo in css but it is not picking up? Thanks

custom.css.scss

```
.sized {
    width: 200px;
}
```

app/views/devise/registrations/edit

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="user-profile">
            <div class="profile-highlight text-center"><h1 class="pad-header">Update</h1></div>
        <div class="user-info">
          <h2>Update <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %> Information</h2>

            <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put, multipart: true }) do |f| %>

            <%= devise_error_messages! %>

            <br>

            <%= f.label :email %>
            <%= f.text_field :email, class: "form-control" %>

            <br>

            <% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
             <p>Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %></p>
            <% end %>

          <%= f.label :address, "Enter your address (it will NOT be displayed publicly)" %>
          <%= f.text_field :address, class: "form-control" %>

          <br>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <%= f.label :city %>
              <%= f.text_field :city, class: "form-control" %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <%= f.label :country %>
              <%= f.text_field :country, autocomplete: "off",  class: "form-control" %>
            </div>
            <br>
          </div>

            <br>
            <br>
            <p><b>Upload pictures of previous projects or work you have done</b></p>

             <div class="sized">
             <%= image_tag @user.portfolio_photo  %>           
            </div>               
            <%= f.file_field :portfolio_photo, multiple: true, name: "user[portfolio_photo]" %>     

            <br>
            <br>

          <p><b>Upload a picture of your mindmeetup location</b></p>

          <%= image_tag @user.location_photo %>

         <%= f.file_field :location_photo, multiple: true, name: "user[location_photo]"  %>
       </div>
     </div>

          <br>

         <div class="text-center"><%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that your tags only include `html` and `css`, I'm assuming you just want to set the css width of the image in question. Do so simply by setting either the `width` or the `height` property, but not both.

http://jsfiddle.net/m1ocvsbq/

```
.sized {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: I did that, put a div on portfolio_photo like so:                  <div class="sized">  <%= image_tag @user.portfolio_photo  %>           
</div> and put what you had above in my custom.css however it does not work.